# Lead and Contact Duplicate Rules Updated?

Tags: leads, duplicate-management

We noticed some unit tests failures in our sandbox environments, and they seem related to duplicate matching rules. We haven't updated the standard rules, but was wondering if Salesforce pushed an update that might have affected those? Has anyone seen issues when converting a lead in the last day or so?

Comment: 1) compare the sandbox default rules to PROD; 2) view setup audit trail to see if any other changes were made to your sandboxes by admins/devs whose side effect is causing dups

Comment: I checked that and there are no changes from what I can see.